# Is it possible convert Postgres dump to csv?

Tags: postgresql, csv, dump

I have Postgres 12.7 dump file (binary format), 300Gb, for simplicity, contains one table.

I want to read the data without installing a server. It would be nice to read the data by converting to csv format on the fly.

Is it possible to read from the dump in any way, preferably with c# or java?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would take you a lot longer to write such a program than to just install Postgres, or spin up a Docker container..

Comment: You can take a look at pgdumblib to read it with python https://github.com/gmr/pgdumplib